# how can i configure oracle1og to access from C#.net

Tags: c#

pls suggest how to configure 10g and which type of connection strings are supplied to c#.net.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install ODP.NET Oracle data access components. It has everything you need. it will just take TNS and user/password to connect. It similar to System.Data.SqlClient but design by oracle for .NET users.  For connection string [read](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle)